# Wordpress Woocommerce custom field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I'm trying to create custom field in woo-commerce (not interested in plugins) in single product and variable product ( custom field price should change according to selected variable option) as that client should be able to enter price as show in 1<sup>st</sup> picture and customer could be able check the option.

**My Requirement**

```
// Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocom_general_product_data_custom_field' );

function woocom_general_product_data_custom_field() {
  // Create a custom text field

  // Text Field
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_text_field', 
      'label' => __( 'Enter your choose', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'placeholder' => 'Custom text field',
      'desc_tip' => 'true',
      'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
  );

  // Number Field
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_number_field', 
      'label' => __( 'Enter your number', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'placeholder' => '', 
      'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ),
      'type' => 'number', 
      'custom_attributes' => array(
         'step' => 'any',
         'min' => '15'
      ) 
    )
  );

  // Checkbox
  woocommerce_wp_checkbox( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_checkbox', 
      'label' => __('Select', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'description' => __( 'Check me!', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
  ); 

  // Select
  woocommerce_wp_select( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_select', 
      'label' => __( 'option', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'options' => array(
         '1' => __( 'Custom Option 1', 'woocommerce' ),
         '2' => __( 'Custom Option 2', 'woocommerce' ),
        '3' => __( 'Custom Option 3', 'woocommerce' )
      )
    )
  );

  // Textarea
  woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
     array( 
       'id' => '_textarea', 
       'label' => __( 'Description', 'woocommerce' ), 
       'placeholder' => '', 
       'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
     )
 );

}

// Hook to save the data value from the custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field' );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_top_category_desc', 1 );
    function woocommerce_template_top_category_desc (){
 $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'wc-attibute-class' );
if ( !empty($terms)) {
        $term = array_pop($terms);
                $text= get_field('txt-field', $term);
                if (!empty($text)) {
                echo $text;
                }
}
        }

/** Hook callback function to save custom fields information */
function woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field( $post_id ) {
  // Save Text Field
  $text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
  if( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $text_field ) );
  }

  // Save Number Field
  $number_field = $_POST['_number_field'];
  if( ! empty( $number_field ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_number_field', esc_attr( $number_field ) );
  }
  // Save Textarea
  $textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
  if( ! empty( $textarea ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $textarea ) );
  }

  // Save Select
  $select = $_POST['_select'];
  if( ! empty( $select ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_select', esc_attr( $select ) );
  }

  // Save Checkbox
  $checkbox = isset( $_POST['_checkbox'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';
  update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkbox', $checkbox );

  // Save Hidden field
  $hidden = $_POST['_hidden_field'];
  if( ! empty( $hidden ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_hidden_field', esc_attr( $hidden ) );
  }
}
```

I have tried some woocommerce custom plugin but it didn't solve my requirement as I have 25 above custom filed to be created and plugin seems to be very lengthy process for my work

My output is in picture 2 which I got from coding for not as my requirement

My output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know you are not interested in plugins, but I highly recommend [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin for custom fields. Check it out, it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: as i have already mention i have to create above 25 custom field for more then 100 products so will it be fruitful....